# Global listener widget

Tags: flutter

I have a `MyListener` widget in a flutter application like following

```dart
class MyListener extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream<ApiEvent> stream;

  const MyListener({
    @required this.stream,
  }) : assert(stream != null);

  @override
  _MyListenerState createState() => _MyListenerState();
}

class _MyListenerState extends State<MyListener> {
  StreamSubscription<MyEvent> eventSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    eventSubscription = stream.listen(onMyEvent);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    eventSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void onMyEvent(MyEvent event) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I want to put `MyListener` widget **once** in the widget tree as a grandchild of the `MaterialApp`, My `MaterialApp` has many `routes` and I don't want to add `MyListener` in all `routes`
I want to only have a `MyListener` in my widget tree to listen to my stream and do something for example show snackbar, route to somewhere, close app, ...

How can I add `MyListener` globally in widget tree as a grandchild of the `MaterialApp`?

Comment: check [How does Flutter InheritedWidget work?](https://medium.com/manabie/how-does-flutter-inheritedwidget-work-3123f9d74c15)

Comment: I asked something else, I want to put a widget GLOBALLY in widget tree, that means the widget exists in whole app lifecycle, Like MaterialApp widget or debug ribbon but once

Comment: there is a `builder` property in `MaterialApp` but honestly how do you want to "access" your widget at runtime? this is why i pointed to `InheritedWidget`

Comment: If in `builder` I return `MyWidget(child:child)` , What happened? is `MyWidget` recreated in multiple routes? or it is only created once?

Comment: Can you clarify that, is it created once?

Answer (score 2):

Widget means drawing layout. What you need is a global service accessible everywhere in your app. Put your `stream` and it's listener in a different dart file|class and call it from your app entry point. `StatefulWidget` has nothing to do there

Comment: I need to access `context`, For instance In some event I need to open a bottom sheet

Comment: What is the best practice for the problem? You must listen to a stream and do an action that need `context` . open a bottom sheet, show a dialog, snackbar, routing ,...

Comment: If you need a global context, accessible even in your services, use this package https://pub.dev/packages/get. Do it as simple as `Get.context` to access your context everywhere

Comment: I am not and don't want to use `GetMaterialApp`

Comment: So you want to run into a complex task

Comment: :-( , Can you explain why it is complex?

Comment: Widget is designed to be layouted not to run global task inside your app. Planning global task in a proper an efficient way requires the usage of services. Unless your provide the app current context using parameter to each function of your service that needs it, if you want to access the context from a listener you may need the help of third party plugin. Doing it yourself, you'll reinvent the wheels by coding more

Comment: Sorry for my english quality, am not a native speaker